# How to change area name in url according to user role in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC app there is a single area folder name with Admin. I want to use same folder for all my user role like SubAdmin, SupAdmin and Admin.

when user login with role super-admin need to show Supadmin in url

Like: http://localhost:4717/supadmin/home

when user login with role admin need to show admin in url

Like: http://localhost:4717/admin/home

when user login with role sub-admin need to show subadmin in url

Like: http://localhost:4717/subadmin/home

How to add routing for It.

Comment: Question: is SubAdmin and SupAdmin additional on top of Admin? Would any user with SubAdmin and SupAdmin be assumed to have Admin role already? Or are they just 3 different roles?